# Why in Oracle forms (based on procedure) query does not return any values?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have made a data block in oracle forms using Data Block Wizzard, however query does not populate the form. Even though cursor returns values and enters the loop in query procedure:

Here is the code of query procedure:

```
PROCEDURE PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES_QUERY(par_pd_pdt_schedule_types_tbl IN OUT gt_pd_pdt_schedule_types_tbl) IS

    lc_err_msg   VARCHAR2(2000);
    lc_add_rec   VARCHAR2(1);
    lc_search_ok VARCHAR2(1);

    CURSOR c_pd_pdt_schedule_types IS
      SELECT pst_code,
             pst_prty,
             pst_mnemo,
             pst_name,
             pst_crt_mandatory,
             pst_pdt_mnemo,
             pst_type,
             pst_purpose,
             pst_purpose_det,
             pst_ref_mnemo,
             pst_hidden,
             pst_ref_show,
             pst_payment_show
      FROM   s_pd_pdt_schedule_types where pst_pdt_mnemo = 'SOME_PRODUCT';

    ln_idx NUMBER := 1;  
 BEGIN    
    FOR i IN c_pd_pdt_schedule_types
    LOOP
      par_pd_pdt_schedule_types_tbl(ln_idx) := i;
      ln_idx := ln_idx + 1;
    END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      lc_err_msg := 'FRL_184.PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES_QUERY error: ' || SQLERRM;
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20555, SUBSTR(lc_err_msg, 1, 2000));
  END PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES_QUERY;
```

Here is the code of form trigger Query-Procedure:

```
DECLARE
bk_data FRL_184.GT_PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES_TBL;
BEGIN
frl_184.PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES_QUERY(bk_data);
PLSQL_TABLE.POPULATE_BLOCK(bk_data, 'S_PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES');
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that `PD_PDT_SCHEDULE_TYPES_QUERY` actually *does something* - test it in SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer or any other tool you use).

`QUERY-PROCEDURE` trigger is created by the Wizard; it is *as is*, there's nothing you should do about it. Forms says that you shouldn't modify it anyway.

In order to make it work, you should edit data block's properties - go to the Palette, navigate to the "Database" section and open **Query data source columns** - in there, you should enter ALL columns returned by the procedure, i.e. `pst_code`, `pst_prty`, etc., along with their datatypes, length, precision ... depending on the datatype itself.

Also, modify **Query data source arguments** property. As your procedure doesn't accept any `IN` parameters, it would be just one argument (`TABLE` type, write its name, mode is `IN OUT`). If you passed some parameters to the procedure, you'd put them in here as well.

That would be it, I think.

Comment: Yes, I have tested in PLSQL developer. It works fine and I am not passing any parameters to the query, because I need full table. 
The issue was that I have added one extra column to the data block in form and *was not pressing refresh button in Data block wizzard*. For this reason, data block wizzard was not picking up my newly added columns.

Comment: OK then, I'm glad you fixed it! Thank you for letting us know.